# How to select columns as CSV in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv, select

Here is the table

```
id    name
----------
1     john
2     dave
3     eve
```

`select * from table` will give us

```
id    name
----------
1     john
2     dave
3     eve
```

How will you query in order to get the below output?

```
id       name
----------------------
1,2,3    john,dave,eve
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to first increase the value of variable group_concat_max_len  so that data shouldn't truncate in group_concat . Check the variable values by command:

```
show variables like 'group_concat_max_len'
```

And increase it as:

```
set global group_concat_max_len = 160000.
```

After this use query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM   table_name
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, name, email INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY ‘\\’
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM users WHERE 1
```

Comment: @Mureinik's solution worked straightforward. Thanks though !